# Calculation of Surface Integration.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, surface-integrals

I've been studying surface integration by myself, but I'm always stuck at the last step. Consider the above question: This is my approach:

Calculation of the curl of the given field.
Calculation of unit vector.
Dot product of the unit vector and the curl of the field.
Then I projected the Hemisphere surface on the $XY$ plane.
In the last step, there is a $Z$.

Now, this is where I face trouble. What should I do with $Z$? Since the area element in the $XY$ plane is
$$ds=dxdy$$
my limits of the integration will be in $X$ and $Y$. I thought of replacing the $Z$ with 0(zero) because I am working in $XY$ plane. But then my integrand would diverge.
My Question and approach are attached.

[image: Question]

[image: Approach]